# Unable to upgrade from 17.04 to 17.10. Could not calculate the upgrade. An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, 17.10

I'm trying `sudo do-release-upgrade` and it fails with the following error:

```
Calculating the changes
Could not calculate the upgrade
An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.
```

`grep Broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log` returns 41 lines indicating problem packages:

```
Broken gnome-control-center-faces:amd64 Conflicts on unity-control-center-faces:amd64 < 15.04.0+17.04.20170402.6-0ubuntu1 @ii mK >
Broken kerneloops:amd64 Breaks on kerneloops-daemon:amd64 < 0.12+git20140509-2ubuntu1 @ii mK > (< 0.12+git20140509-6ubuntu1)
Broken linux-tools-4.10.0-35-generic:amd64 Depends on linux-tools-4.10.0-35:amd64 < 4.10.0-35.39 @ii mR >
Broken xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-20:amd64 < none @un H >
...
```

I think that a solution is to delete these packages, but I'm afraid that I can accidentally break something (and Linux won't boot).

How to solve this issue in a safe way?

Comment: Uninstall ALL non-Ubuntu software that you installed from non-Ubuntu sources, PPAs, websites, etc. Return your packages to as close to stock condition as possible. Yes, you will likely lose video so do it from a text console.